# How can I perform an action on all list elements at the same time on python

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have `my_list = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]`

I want to perform an action on all elements at the same time instead of using a for loop. 
For example, like printing below at the same time:

```
fruit is apple 
fruit is banana
fruit is cherry
```

Comment: map method in the multiprocessing module is your friend.

Comment: @Lyokolux, using threads you can not guarantee that all elements of the list will be processed in the **same** moment of time

Comment: That's impossible. Even with threads it will be always one after an other. What you want is like getting three persons at once through a door that's one person wide.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. I got the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be very careful about how you word things. The way your question is phrased, you're making it sound like you want to perform three things instantaneously. With a question like that, people will naturally recommend things like threading, or even give you lectures about how that is impossible with computers in general. If that's not the question you're asking (which I think it's not), it's just a big waste of time for everybody.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what you ACTUALLY want to know is how to print three distinct things on the same line, without introducing any newline characters.

```
>>> fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
>>> print(fruits)
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
>>> print(*fruits)
apple banana cherry
>>> print(*(f"fruit is {f}" for f in fruits))
fruit is apple fruit is banana fruit is cherry
>>>
```

If this answers your question, please note, that the three strings are still being printed one after the other. There is nothing instantaneous about it.